# Cheap SIPP providers in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, pension

What are cheap SIPP providers in the UK? I would be saving around £333 each month in a SIPP starting from zero (all my previous pension contributions are in an employer-organizaed group pension plan). What provider would you recommend in my situation?

I would be mostly investing in funds, occasionally in individual stocks and ETFs. Due to financial market regulations, I need to ask my employer's compliance department for permission whenever I buy stocks or ETFs, so regular investment in them is out of the question (but I can do it in mutual funds/OEICs).

Comment: Closing this as it's off-topic now - I guess it wasn't when originally asked.

Answer (score 4):

I investigated this carefully a couple of years back, and the two I looked at most closely were [Hargreaves Lansdown](http://www.hl.co.uk/pensions/sipp/charges-and-interest-rates) and [EPML's Global Investment SIPP](https://www.epml.co.uk/sipp/epm-global-investment-sipp-selftrade-sipp-dealing-account-1).

In the end I chose EPML, but I think in your circumstances with a relatively small amount to invest initially, Hargreaves Lansdown would work best as the charges are in proportion to the amount you have invested (but capped), whereas EPML has a flat fee.

Answer (score 2):

I have good things about SIPP deal but having never used them myself am unable to comment first hand.

Something to bear in mind is that whilst you may be aware of the effect of charges and understand their impact longer term, its highly unlikely the charging structures will persist for 20 years; even 5 years has seen substantial changes.

So there's no guarantee that the cheapest today will be the cheapest over the period you plan to hold the investment.

SIPP deal are one of the cheapest for normal shares but their fund charge rebate isn't among the best have a look at this page which has small price comparison table (not sure how up to date it is)
http://www.candidmoney.com/actionplans/actionplan.aspx

Comment: I have an ISA with SippDeal and they allow buying non-UK shares (as long as they are CREST-settled), something which BestInvest doesn't. Are there any other cheap SIPPs apart from those listed in the table you linked to?

Comment: There are many more depends on how you define cheap, most brokerages offer a SIPP account but their prices/costs will vary.

Comment: Well, the cheaper the better ;-)

Comment: It depends on what will you doing within the SIPP as they charge different amounts for buying stocks as they do for holding funds, so one may be cheaper for someone holding more funds and another for someone holding more stocks, also some such as the alliance trust one have annual fees but give a bigger rebate on fund charges so will perform better than others if you have a certain of money invested.
It's a very nuanced topic that you should read up on yourself and become aware of all the costs and how they differs from providers.

Comment: I can always start with one SIPP provider and, after gathering a significant amount, move to a different one...

Comment: A lot of SIPP providers also have transfer out fees, which is another thing to bear in mind, although some provides may give you incentives to switch to them such as rebating the charges from the original provider.